# Can you send web services from Lotus Notes

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes

Are you able to send web services from Lotus Notes?

We have a booking system that is hosted in Lotus Notes which we are hoping to push some content to a web based system. We were initially thinking a .csv file with the data but were wondering whether it's possible to push this data using web services instead?

Answer (score 5):

You mean you want to consume a web service from Lotus Notes? The answer is yes, it is actually pretty easy, and well documented in the Domino Designer help:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_INCORPORATING_WEB_SERVICES_LIBRARY.html

Another good link is this one:

[Creating your first Web Service provider and consumer in LotusScript and Java.](https://ibm.biz/BdRrcq)